# How to save a Vim macro that contains "Escape" key presses?

Tags: vim, macros

I use the following Vim macro a lot (it puts the current line inside XML tags):

```
I<e>^[A</e>
```

So I saved it into my .vimrc

```
let @e='I<e>^[A</e>'
```

But it does not work.
The `^[` part means "Escape" but it is not understood as such in `.vimrc`

How can I save this macro, or any macro that contains "Escape" ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try entering the escape with `<Ctrl-v><Esc>` in insert mode.
See `:help i_CTRL-V` in vim.

Comment: No it shouldn't. With <ctrl-V><esc> the ^[ is a single charater (escaped code for ESC), not the '^' and '[' characters. Just tested it again in vim and gvim 7.2, it correctly wraps a line in tags.

Comment: simple test, when you move the cursor along the ^[ part, you shouldn't be able to place it between the ^ and [, as it represents a single keycode.

Comment: The trick was indeed this single keycode character, I didn't see difference at first. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not sure if my google-fu was just bad, but I couldn't find any other hints of the right way to do this on all of the internets.

Answer (score 25):

For a **macro**:

```
:let @e='^[I<e>^[A</e>'
```

Where `^[` is just one char formed by hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd> (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd> on Windows). Note the escape right at the beginning of the macro.

See [`:help c_CTRL-V`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#c_CTRL-V) in Vim for more information.

---

For those who've landed on this post looking for how to add <kbd>ESC</kbd> to a **mapping**, the answer is different.

Literally type <kbd><</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>C</kbd><kbd>></kbd>, thus:

```
:nnoremap <Leader>E I<e><ESC>A</e><ESC>
```

See [`:help key-notation`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#key-notation) in Vim for more info.

Comment: Now I think I understand what you mean by "does not work". Answer updated.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot :-D The trick was to use this single character instead of ^[ Now I realize catchmeifyoutry had the solution!

Comment: Glad you got it working. You may find that `map`-pings are more useful if you have a lot of such shortcuts as they do not trample on your `registers`.

Comment: Indeed, mappings seems to be more appropriate for my usage, thanks again :-)

Comment: @Johnsyweb Yes. Great explanation! Couldn't find this anywhere else. This finally solved my problem for how to embed an escape. Thank you!

Comment: You should remove the wrong suggestion. It's an unnecessary noise. I was trying to get it work for past half an hour. Please make the updated version the default one.

Comment: I'm sorry my 9 year-old answer cost you so much time @ashrasmun. I've used the edit functionality to make the answer clearer.

Comment: @Johnsyweb Thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

For readability purpose, it's possible to use the proper key-notation tags such as `<Esc>` or `<CR>` instead of `^[` or `^M`

You would need to escape the tag `<Esc>` with a single `\` and use double quotes instead of single quotes which would result in `"\<Esc>"`.
The following examples are equivalent

```
:let @e='^[I<e>^[A</e>'
:let @e="\<Esc><e>\<Esc>A</e>"
```

A list of all key notations can be found by typing `:help key-notation` or [here](https://vimhelp.org/intro.txt.html#key-notation).

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Windows behavior for vim where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> is the Paste command, the equivalent sequence is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Today I discovered a vim plug-in called MARVIM (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2154).

It is capable of storing macros and executing them later using shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

Saving macros in plain file without plugins.

Having for example macro **m** . In insert mode, at e.g beginning of new line, then type 3 keys

> **ctrl-r ctrl-r m**

the macro with escapes will be put in that line. (editable as needed)
In another line name/comment it.
Add other macros if you wish - then  save this file as e.g. 
:w my_vim_macros

When you want to reuse such saved macro(s):
place cursor on the beginning of macro string, then 4keys

> **"xy$**

and your macro (this line) will be yanked to register **x**.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering what I do to add **Escape** in macro.

Using in vim editor

```
:let @a='iabcjj'
```

here I map `<ESC>` to `jj` by

.vimrc file

```
imap jj <esc>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue why, but other solutions just wouldn't work.

So I defined a macro that puts a hash before the first character of a line then moves down a line like so:

```
let @a = "^i# " . nr2char(27) . "j"
```

where

- `let @a =`  says: defining a macro..
- `^i#`  says: place a hash before the first non-space character in the line
- `. nr2char(27) .` the escape!
- `j` says: move down a line

So in summary (I *guess*) `nr2char(27)` makes an escape key press, and you just have to sort of join it to the other bits of your macro with a dot each side and surround the other bits with double quotes.

Try adding the one above then tinkering with it, should only take a second to grok.