# Saving a macro in vim with <Esc>

Tags: vim, macros

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024443/saving-vim-macros) explained saving a vim macro to a file but I cannot get it to work.  I have the following macro stored in register b that I am trying to save to my rst.vim file:

```
let @b = '<Esc>bea**<Esc>`<i**<Esc>gvoo<Esc>e'
```

Everything inside of '...' came from pasting the macro from the buffer using `"bp`.  But when I close and reopen a rst file containing only the sentence `The quick brown fox jumped over the moon` and type `fbv2e@b`, this is the resulting sentence:

```
Thc>bea**<Esc>`<i**<Esc>gvoo<Esc>e quick brown fox jumped over the moon.
```

So, there must be some escape keystrokes I am missing, but I can't find what they are.  I tried searching google and `:help` for similar macro examples with no avail.  What am I missing and what terms should I be looking for when searching?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that you have the escape character and not the characters `<`, `E`, `s`, `c` and `>` ? It worked for me when I tested.

Comment: I do have `<,E,s,c,>` because that is what got pasted in from `"bp`.  I know that when looking at `:reg b` it is using `<Esc>` instead.  How can I insert `<Esc>` into a text file?  *UPDATE:* I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943555/how-to-save-a-vim-macro-that-contains-escape-key-presses) which answers my question.

Comment: I don't like having literal control characters somewhere, so I would have used `"\e"` for escape and `"\<C-C>"` for other control characters (`"\<Esc>"` also works). Note the double quotes.

Comment: @ZyX thanks!  I like that much better as well.

Comment: Similar to earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943555

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As hinted at by some, the problem was that `<Esc>` actually was `<`,`E`,`s`,`c`,`>`.  Vim generates escapes in a text file using `C-v <ESC>`.  So I ran `:s/<Esc>/^[/g` on the `:let` line in the question.  ***Note that `^`,`[` is not the same as the `^[` generated by `C-v <Esc>`!***

To save myself a headache a few months from now, I switched `^[` to `\e`.  I had to make sure I surrounded the macro in double quotes because single quotes didn't work.

Comment: `\e` and double quotes appears to be the only solution working for me in a `nnoremap` setting. `<Esc>` or `^[` would result in `E114: Missing quote`.