# Insert predefined text on keyboard shortcut

Tags: vim

I often insert `binding.pry` to my ruby files when I debug them. As I use Vim I'd love to automate it to avoid retyping it every time. How could I do it?

The exact sequence I'd like to map is:

1. Insert new line.
2. Insert `binding.pry` to the newly created line.
3. Return to normal mode.

**EDIT:** `binding.pry` is text I want to paste, not a file.

Before insert:

```
a = 1
b = 2
```

After insert:

```
a = 1
binding.pry
b = 2
```

Comment: Do you mean insert the text "binding.pry", or insert the content of the file `binding.pry`?

Comment: As I wrote in a comment for an answer: it's a text 'binding.pry' not content of a file.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Record a macro (untested)

```
qq               " record macro to register q 
o                " insert empty line below cursor
esc              " exit insert-mode
:r /path/to/binding.pry   " insert content of file
esc              " cmd-mode
q                " end recording
```

To execute macro, do

```
@q
```

Or add the following to your `.vimrc` file

**update**

To insert the string `binding.pry` the mapping becomes:

```
map ,p obinding.pry<ESC>
```

Comment: Thanks! One comment: `binding.pry` is not a file, but a string that I'd like to paste. It should be easier, am I right?

Comment: @mrzasa, just skip the `esc` and `:r ...` steps and just replace with  `binding.pry`.

Comment: @FredrikPihl If I want to add `obinding.pry`?

Answer (score 13):

Easiest is an *abbreviation* that is triggered from insert mode:

```
:ia debug <CR>binding.pry
```

Now, when you type `debug`, the text `binding.pry` is inserted on a new line.

Documentation: `:help abbreviations`

Comment: Well you'll need to go into insert mode and type a few words, so not exactly the easiest.

Answer (score 6):

Another mapping that will do is:

```
nnoremap <silent> gb :let a='binding.pry'\|put=a<cr>
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on [Fredrik's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17086457/912144), you can define and store a macro in your `.vimrc`, say `g`:

```
let @g = "Obinding.pry^["
```

Note that to [type the escape character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2943565/912144) you hit <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd> then <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

You can then do `@g` to perform the macro.

---

In general, if you want to save a macro, one easy way would be to record the macro, say in register `q`, then do `"qp` (where `q` is the macro name) to paste the macro. Then surround it with

```
let @x = "..."
```

where `x` is the macro name you want it to always have and put it in the `.vimrc` file.

Comment: For more information see [Saving vim macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024443/saving-vim-macros)

Comment: For the escape character, this worked for me: In Vim Insert Mode hit `ctrl+q` then `ESC`

Comment: here is what I'm using:
`let @b="obinding.pry^[0"` Use lowercase 'o' to insert below current line. Use 0 (zero) to go to the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 1):

A great quandary I found myself in. To solve this I placed the following mappings in my .vimrc:

```
imap <C-b> binding.pry 
nnoremap <leader>bp O<% binding.pry %><esc>
```

The first allows me to use  to insert a binding.pry when already in insert mode.

The second lets me use my leader+bp to place a binding.pry above the current line.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a shortcut for this purpose with the following key strokes

1. :vsplit $MYVIMRC
2. i
3. nnoremap bi obinding.pry<cr><esc>
4. <esc>
5. :w
6. :source $MYVIMRC

Explaination

1. Open your vimrc in a new vertical splitted window
2. Switch to insert mode
3. Define a mapping for the shortcut 'bi'.
4. Leave insert mode
5. Save the changes
6. Source your vimrc to make the shortcut available

Now, while you in normal mode, the keystrokes <b><i> (one key after each other) will insert 'binding.pry' in a new line under the current line.

Explaination for step 3:
nnoremap is the command for mapping keystroke(s) to do some action. 'bi' is the keystroke combination. You can adjust this to your needs. And the rest is a normal edit sequenz on VIM:

- o - Switch to insert mode under the current line
- binding.pry<cr> - is the text which will be writen
- <esc> - Push escape to leave insert mode.