# How to execute a vim macro string in command line?

Tags: vim, macros, command-line-interface

Macro in Vim is extremely useful to perform tasks that is difficult to finish in normal command line tool (`sed`, `awk`, `perl`, etc.), is there any way to perform that kinds of macro string in command line?

Something like the following:

```
// execute macro stored in register a 100 times for filenames
vim execute -s "100@a" filenames [filenames2, filenames3, ...]
```

Comment: `vim -s` runs a script from the command line.  Getting it right can be tricky though.

Answer (score 4):

For those having trouble to execute a number of normal commands (like a macro) and exiting again, it is possible to first define the macro.

```sh
vim files* -c "let @l=\"ggOStart\<Esc>GoEnd\<Esc>\" | argdo normal @l | ZZ"
```

The command will insert "Start" to the beginning of each file starting with `files*` and "End" to the end, but an arbitrary macro might be applied.

That way it's possible to define and execute a macro without it being already present. You will have to use and escape double quotes `\"` if you want to be using any key-notation such as `\<Esc>` mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943555/how-to-save-a-vim-macro-that-contains-escape-key-presses/56506589#56506589).

By adding `ZZ` to the end, the file is written and closed again. Commands can be concatenated by a `|` symbol.

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there:

```
$ vim file* -c "argdo norm 100@a"
```